# Unknow error while building the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

Me and my friend developing an app, by synchronizing it on bitBucket.org. My friend added a external library to the project and when I pulled the project, It is giving me the following error while building the project.:

[image]

When I pulled the project, the error message was appeared: `Error loading 3 modules`. In details option, It was something about .iml files. I selected the option `keep all`.

Image of project structure and gradle file is:
[image]

I've searched too many times on internet about this, but can get exact solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried Build Clean?

Comment: do you mean clean project? then yes, I've tried.

Comment: Yes. Clean project and try rebuild.

Comment: same error appears

Comment: Try using buildToolsVersion as 23.0.3 in your app gradle file.

Comment: that also not working